# SharePoint add break after span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I have a question about jquery SharePoint add break after span element.
I have a taxonomy field with single line of tekst. I want to break evry field  with a break.

With Jquery il try the first element and the second element span.

```
$("[id^='Stukken_x0020_toevoegen']").children('span').append( "<br />" );
```

what am I doing wrong

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to `display` - `block` `span`

```
.valid-text{display:block;}
```

Comment: This works .ms-taxonomy span {
 display:block!important;
}